# Once I stop removing my pepper plant's flower buds, how long will it take for fruit to mature?

Tags: peppers

I live in zone 5a, with a fairly short growing season.  I'd like to try to maximize my hot pepper harvest by continuing to remove flower buds (to promote plant growth), while still allowing for enough time for the flowers to be pollinated and produce mature fruit before frost sets in (October 1 is about the average).

The peppers I'm growing are a mix--jalapenos, cayenne, tabasco, "super pepper", and a couple others.

Approximately how long should I expect it to take for flowering through fruit maturing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a jalapeño growing this year and it took about 5-6 weeks for the first fruit to become fully ripe (red). I'm in zone 7b/8a.

I would note that I've grown peppers for many years and never remove buds. I don't believe it to be necessary unless the plant is very small.